# Src folder disappears in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

My project consists of 3 modules. If I set everything up from scratch I am able to see all folders including the src catalogues. As soon as I press tools -> Manage Python Packages and install a package the src catalogue for one of the modules disappears (same every time). I have tried to recreate the project several times, downgrading intellij to an earlier version, removing the .Idea... folder form my home directory and setting it all up from scratch. 
The problem still persists, as soon as I install a package the src folder from the same module is not visible.

What's interesting is that if I go to project structure (F4) I can see same folder that is missing.

OS: Debian 9
Idea version: 18.1.6 / 18.2 Community edition.

Anyone that has seen this issue?

Comment: Could you please file an issue about it to the corresponding issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY and attach screenshots/screencast that show the issue? Thank you.